# Replace em um objeto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu faço uma chamada `Ajax` e essa chamada me retorna alguns dados. Eu preciso passar um dado de `descrição`, é uma string com um texto, porém para passar esses dados no modal estou utilizando o `data-` e para isso preciso converter para texto. Estou buscando um método para poder formatar essa `descricao` dentro do modal. Removendo o `&nbsp` e colocando no lugar um `<br>`.

**Como está sendo feito o data**

```
var descricao = $(json[i].descricao).text(); //Converter para texto, pois ela vem com as tags html

<div class="card opModalGaleria" id="`+json[i].seq_membro_galeria+`" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGaleria" data-descricao="`+descricao+`">
```

E dai na hora de exibir não estou conseguindo substituir os `&nbsp` por `<br>` para formatar corretamente no modal a `descrição`.

```
$('#modalGaleria').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var descricao = button.data('descricao')
    var descricaoFormatada = descricao.replace(/&nbsp;/g,"<br/>")
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('#descricaoModal').text(descricaoFormatada)
})
```

Comment: O replace me parece correto. Não está fazendo a substituição?

Comment: Aqui: `modal.find('#descricaoModal').text(descricaoFormatada)` teria que ser `modal.find('#descricaoModal').html(descricaoFormatada)` para o `<br>` funcionar como HTML.

Comment: @Sam já esta como html porém mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: O replace não está funcionando? O que não está funcionando?

Comment: Não está funcionando o replace, queria substituir pela tag <br> mas o replace não esta causando efeito nenhum.

Comment: tente fazer `var descricaoFormatada = descricao.toString().replace(/&nbsp;/g,"<br/>")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o `&nbsp;` é lido como um espaço simples.

Troque o `&nbsp;` no replacce por `\s`, que representa um espaço na regex:

```
descricao.replace(/\s/g,"<br/>")
```

E troque `.text` por `.html` nesta linha para que o `<br>` seja interpretado como HTML e não como texto puro:

```
modal.find('#descricaoModal').html(descricaoFormatada)
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var descricao = button.data('descricao')
    var descricaoFormatada = descricao.replace(/\s/g,"<br>")
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('#descricaoModal').html(descricaoFormatada)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-descricao="123&nbsp;abc&nbsp;def">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <span id="descricaoModal"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.